# Why wont setContentView recognize my second activity xml?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have tried to serach this website/ the web for a similar question but nobodies question seems to be the same...

Just trying to display a layout I have made for my second activity xml file but when I call `setContentView(R.layout.blah)` it only recongnizes my `main layout` rather than the one I just created and I do not know why...

So when I'm typing it in the auto fill does not display an option for it..

I'm using `Eclipse` for my IDE

onCreate()

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.blah);


}
```

blah xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.studentgrades.Grade1"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/class1Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="@string/class1Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/inspectionOfClass1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inspectionOfClass1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
        android:hint="@string/mathHint1"  />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inspectionOfClass4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inspectionOfClass2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:text="@string/mathGrade4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inspectionOfClass3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/inspectionOfClass4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inspectionOfClass4"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
       android:text="@string/mathGrade3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inspectionOfClass2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/inspectionOfClass1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:text="@string/mathGrade2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inspectionOfClass1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/class1Name"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="@string/mathGrade1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inspectionOfClass2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/class1Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
        android:hint="@string/mathHint2"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inspectionOfClass3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
        android:hint="@string/mathHint3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/inspectionOfClass4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inspectionOfClass1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" 
        android:hint="@string/mathHint4"   />
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: No, I have tried that before and i couldn't figure out how to get everything working again after I cleaned it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your RelativeLayout has a closing tag, have you checked to make sure you have "blah.xml" in the layouts folder of /res?

Comment: Yes... I figured it out, it was because my `strings.xml` got corrupted somehow and had wrong values in it?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if you have imported the correct R.java file - com.yourpackagename.R ?

Comment: Yes I have checked that already, or at least I think I have lol